# PHP progress bar not working

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

Both html and java script files are on the same page

HTML code corresponding to it is:

```
<body>
    <div id="outer_pog">
        <div id="inner_pog">
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="hidden_frame">
        <input type="hidden" value="myform" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name");  ?>" />
        <input type="file" name="userfile" />   <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="start upload" />

    </form>
    <iframe name="hidden_frame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
    <span></span>
</body>
```

javascript code is:

```
$(function(){
        $('#myform').submit(function(e){      
          $.get('progress.php',function(dt){
             $('span').html(dt);
             setTimeout(prog,1000);
          });
        })
     });
     function prog(){
         $.get('progress.php',function(dt){
             $('span').html(dt);
             if(dt<100)
             {
                 setTimeout(prog,1000);
             }
          });
     }
```

when I run this i always getting 100 in return,when I debugged it in netbean value of 
$_SESSION[$key] is always array[0].

php code i.e progress.php , is below:

```
<?php
session_start();
$key=  ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix")."myform";
if(!empty($_SESSION[$key])){
 $cur=$_SESSION[$key]['bytes_processed'];
 $tot=$_SESSION[$key]['content_length'];
 echo $cur<$tot ? ceil($cur/$tot*100) : 100;
 }
else
echo 100;
?>
```

Comment: have you started the session before showing the form?

Comment: No should that be started ??

Comment: though I have started there is no much difference

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the $key variable? Is there any?
If you check the source code is there a name for the hidden input?

The top comment in [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) states that: "Note, this feature doesn't work, when your webserver is runnig PHP via FastCGI. There will be no progress informations in the session array.
Unfortunately PHP gets the data only after the upload is completed and can't show any progress."
So, check your webservers settings.
But, I would recommend you to use the [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) plugin for jQuery.